# Como saber si todos los input han sido llenados

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy realizando una práctica en *javascript* y estoy intentando validar que todos los campos de los `<input>`s estén llenos, para después mostrar el botón de enviar formulario, pero al momento de validar que cada `<input>` esté lleno, se genera el botón con tan solo un `<input>` lleno, cuando el botón se debe mostrar cuando todos los `<input>`s se llenen

```js
const form = document.querySelectorAll('.form__element-input');
const boton = document.querySelector('#enviar');

form.forEach((input, index) => {
    boton.classList.add('none__send');
    input.addEventListener('change', () => {
        if (input.value.trim() !== '') {
            boton.classList.remove('none__send');
            return;
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.none__send {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__title">
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="cedula" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__button">
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al recorrer todos los elementos, añades un `eventListener` a cada uno, ese evento se ejecutará cuando se escribe en el `<input>`, haciendo que cuando se escriba en ese elemento, se muestre el botón sin importar si los otros estén llenos, debes usar el selector con `querySelectorAll` otra vez, este método te da un `NodeList`, el cual no tiene métodos nativos de un array como [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), por lo que lo podemos convertir de una manera simple

```
[...querySelectorAll("...")]
```

De esta manera concatenamos lo que esté adentro del iterable valor de retorno de `querySelectorAll` a un array, convirtiendo todo a un array

El propósito de esto es que una vez sea un array, usar [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) para comprobar si hay algún `<input>` vacío

```js
const form = [...document.querySelectorAll('.form__element-input')];
const boton = document.querySelector('#enviar');

form.forEach((input, index) => {
    boton.classList.add('none__send');
    input.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (form.some(el => el.value.trim() === "")) {
            boton.classList.add('none__send');
        } else {
            boton.classList.remove('none__send');
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.none__send {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" class="form">
    <div class="form__title">
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="cedula" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="number" name="telefono" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__element">
        <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form__element-input"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form__button">
        <button type="submit" id="enviar">enviar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Gran respuesta muchas gracias